# solar panel cracks, are they affecting output?

Tags: solar, pv, photovoltaic, cracked

[image: cracked cell 01]

[image: cracked cell 03]

[image: cracked cell 04]

The above photos were taken today. They appear to show cracked cells within at least four panels. There are more, but these were the ones I could reach for photos. The panels were cleaned yesterday, using plain water fed through a panel cleaning brush. The cracked cells were detected prior to the cleaning.

There's no surface disruption. There are no trees which could drop branches or other debris to create such cracks. The panels were heavily contaminated with pollen which was relatively easy to clean and I'm hopeful that the performance will improve for that reason.

It's early in the season of sunshine here in the sunshine state, but 6.5 kW from an eleven kiloWatt array seems low.

Contacting the PV operation responsible for our installation, sending the photos, resulted in what I would call a dismissal of my concerns. The statement effectively said that the impact of one cell would be insignificant.

This is an Enphase Energy system with microinverters for each panel. I can access reports from the web interface, but I'm not sure what to seek. Should I be attempting to identify each panel with a cracked cell (or more) to compare to adjacent uncracked panel performance?

One question carries the post: am I losing performance?

Comment: All panels should output ~ the same, at the same time of day.  If you can compare cracked from uncracked panels, then it should show if cracked is under performing.  I think there is surface cover and the work is done under the surface, but surface cracks might let in weather/rain/dirt that will hurt in time.

Comment: i have 2 panels next to each other, performance varies at the sun moves east to west but seems to be 37 vs 35 watts or 12 vs 11 watts or 256 vs 264.  So I suppose performance is close except at low levels where it is +-10% between the panels.  Might be position of sun or cleanliness of the panel.  I think this variation was there when the panels were brand new - mine are from 2019.

Answer (score 1):

If you have reporting at the microinverter level, at a time when the whole array is in sun, compare the outputs of the different panels.

You could also look at historical data, where there's an expected inital overproduction and gradual decrease with time, but if things cracked post-installation you might find a sudden drop on particular panels.

Comment: Your suggestion appears to be quite good. In order to properly approach this method, I'll have to climb above and chart the panels with cracks, to assign the correct ones to the web interface. I'm hopeful there's a CSV download option or some other mass download of the desired information.